# spring boot override bean in different jar cause ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, classnotfoundexception

I ve a "core" application how I want to be "pluginable", so I write some interface and relatives empty bean just to "holding the place"

Project 1 Void Bean

```
public class VoidDirectiveWriter implements DirectiveWriter {
    private org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger log = org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(VoidDirectiveWriter.class);

    @Override
    public void writeDirective(InputStream directive, Date... ts) {
        log.info("do-nothing");
    }
}
```

Project1 Endpoint file

```
..
@Autowired
    private DirectiveWriter                 directiveWriter;
..
```

Project1 Configuration file

```
@Configuration
public class PackageBundleBeanDefinition {
    @Bean
    public DirectiveWriter getDirectiveWriter() {
        return new VoidDirectiveWriter();
    }
}
```

so, I build the plugin-project with those pieces of codes:

Project 2 not-void Bean

```
public class ScsperfWriter implements DirectiveWriter {
    @Override
    public void writeDirective(InputStream is, Date... ts) {
do stuff
    }
}
```

Project 2 configuration file

```
@Configuration
public class ScsperBeanDefinition {
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DirectiveWriter getDirectiveWriter() {
        return new ScsperfWriter();
    }
}
```

I use Eclipse, if I try to run core project on its own all works fine (void bean trigger), if I try to add the plugin jar build via maven at the project-1 classpath all works as I aspect ( ScsperfWriter bean trigger ) but when i try to run them out of the developement environement via script **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException** appear. If I try to remove plugins folder from classpath all work fine ( void bean trigger )

this is the script

```
@echo off

set cp="plugins\pb-report-scsperf.jar;bin\poc-spring-e1packagebundle.jar"
rem set cp="bin\poc-spring-e1packagebundle.jar"
set java_exe=java
set log4j2_config=config\log4j.xml
set application_config=config\application.properties

java -cp %cp% -Dlogging.config=%log4j2_config% -Dloader.main=it.m2sc.PackageBundle org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher --application.properties=%application_config%
```

can anyone help me ? sorry for my english, i'm in rush !

Comment: Did you try spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true this configuration in application.properties ?

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: Can you show the exact error message? Also what Java and Spring Boot version are you using?

Comment: spring boot 1.5.8.RELEASE